# Change color of input and fa icon when input is texted

Tags: html, css

I want to change the color of input and the  related glyph-icon icon color when text is entered however I have changed the text color using css when text is entered but glyph-icon color doesn't changes

**html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" name="customerBidId" [(ngModel)]="createPlan.customerBidId" placeholder="Bid ID" required>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
input:focus + .glyphicon {
  color: #39529d;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #39529d;
}
```

on focus glyphicon color and text color changes but when focus is removed the the text colors sustain the but glyphicon gets back to default color

Comment: You must use only `css`?

Comment: it can be scss if its not possible

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your text color is always `#39529d` since you've hard-coded that value on the `input` tag using your second line of CSS.

Your first line will color the glyphicon *only* if the direct previous sibling `input` is being focused.

```
input:focus + .glyphicon {
  color: #39529d;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus{
  color: #39529d;
}
```

This code should make sure your text will only be colored whenever the element is focused.

```
input + .glyphicon {
  color: #39529d;
}
input, textarea{
  color: #39529d;
}
```

And this code will always color it.

Comment: its not satisfying the condition because the glyphicon and text color should be changed only when  focuse or i have data in my input field

Comment: Ah, so if there's content inside the input, you'd wish to color the glyph?

Comment: yeah exaclty otherwise the default color

Comment: Ah, that's not possible with mere CSS.

Comment: Is JavaScript allowed?

Comment: its better to do it using scss or css however if not possible in any case will go for js

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can achieve this,

```js
$('#myText').blur(function(){
  if(this.value){
     $('.glyphicon').attr('style', 'color: red');
  } else {
     $('.glyphicon').attr('style', 'color: #39529d');
  }
})
```

```css
input:focus + .glyphicon {
  color: red;
}
input, select, textarea{
  color: #39529d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="form-control" id="myText" name="customerBidId" [(ngModel)]="createPlan.customerBidId" placeholder="Bid ID" required>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i>
  </div>
```